# How to add two trailing icons on Material3 Search Bar on Android?

Tags: android, xml, material-components-android, android-search

**I want to add two trailing icons (one of them being the 3 dots menu icon) on my [Material 3 Search Bar](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/Search.md).**

Examples:
[image: Source: GitHub]Source: [GitHub](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/Search.md)

and this:
[image]
Source: [Material 3](https://m3.material.io/components/search/specs#3abcc5f8-e08f-467d-884a-49b03c1abefe)

But I can't find any way to do this nor any documentation anywhere in Google's repos or Material's regarding this. It's in their guides, it should had a quick and easy way to do it, no?

My code right now which successfully shows the menu is this:

```
   <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <com.google.android.material.search.SearchBar
            android:id="@+id/searchBar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/search_here"
            app:menu="@menu/explorer_menu"
            app:navigationIcon="@drawable/ic_logo" />
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.search.SearchView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:closeIcon="@drawable/ic_close"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/searchBar">
        <!-- Search suggestions/results go here (ScrollView, RecyclerView, etc.). -->
    </com.google.android.material.search.SearchView>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you figured it out?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to add trailing icons to search bar, you have to create menu for it. The `SearchBar` component is a child of a Toolbar, so you can specify menu value for it.
The `SearchBar` does not have special "trailing-icon" field and google has to add it in their M3 implementation documentation.

Here's the example from my project:

searchbar_menu.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item android:id="@+id/menu_sort"
        android:icon="@drawable/sort"
        android:title="@string/sort"
        app:showAsAction="always"/>
    <item android:id="@+id/menu_trend"
        android:icon="@drawable/trending"
        android:title="@string/trend"
        app:showAsAction="always"/>
    <item android:id="@+id/menu_options"
        android:icon="@drawable/options"
        android:title="@string/options"
        app:showAsAction="always"/>

</menu>
```

Layout file:

```xml
<com.google.android.material.search.SearchBar
                        android:id="@+id/search_bar"
                        android:hint="@string/search"
                        app:menu="@menu/searchbar_menu" />
```

As a result, you get a search bar with always showing three icons at the end.

In order to better understand menu in android, I'd suggest you to look for the documentation in android-developers website.